# Splitting one table into multiple tables based on columns using velocity

Tags: java, html, velocity, vtl

Ok below is the code that i have. Here we read a map from a JAVA object and populate columns based on the key and values of the map. The Java object map is of the form

`HashMap<HashMap<String, Object>>`.

The required table will have columns equal to number of outer hashmap. The row count will be equal to number of Sting/Objects in the inner hashmap.

Following is the code which generates table. As described above, the number of columns in the table will depend on the values in the java object. The problem we are facing is, if the value in hashmap is above 10 then PDH generation resuls in loss of data.

```
    <table style="font-family:Arial;font-size:xx-small;color:black" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     #set ($allLegs = $ConfirmationObject.getAllLegs())
     #set ($i = 1)
     <tr>
         <td valign="top" width="30%"> </td>
           #foreach($legSzie in $allLegs.keySet())
               <td valign="top" width="30%" align="left"><b>Leg $i</b></td>
               #set ($i=$i+1)
           #end
          <tr><td></td></tr>
          <td valign="top" width="10%" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>

     <td colspan="1">
         <table style="font-family:Arial;font-size:xx-small;color:black" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
             #set ($map = $ConfirmationObject.getLegMap(1))
             #foreach($key in $map.keySet())
                  <tr>
                     <td valign="top" width="60%">$key </td>
                  </tr>
             #end
         </table>
     </td>

     #foreach($legString in $allLegs.keySet())
       <td colspan="1">
            <table style="font-family:Arial;font-size:xx-small;color:black" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                #set ($legMap = $allLegs.get($legString))
                #foreach($legKey in $legMap.keySet())
                   <tr>
                       <td >$legMap.get($legKey)</td>
                   </tr>
                #end
            </table>
       </td>
     #end
    </table>
```

Expectation:
Is it possible to have the data split into different tables when ever the column value reaches more than 3?

so for example consider a scenario where the table looks like

```
            LEG 1        LEG 2       LEG 3        LEG 4       LEG 5
A           12           13          14           15          16
B           12           13          14           15          16          
C           12           13          14           15          16
D           12           13          14           15          16
E           12           13          14           15          16
```

How can we split this like

```
            LEG 1        LEG 2       LEG 3        
A           12           13          14          
B           12           13          14                    
C           12           13          14           
D           12           13          14          
E           12           13          14 




            LEG 4        LEG 5       
A           15           16                   
B           15           16                              
C           15           16                     
D           15           16                   
E           15           16
```

Comment: what is the ConfirmationObject?

Comment: @MauricePerry : thats just the name of java collection of the form hashmap<hashmap<string, object>>

Comment: OK, so what are the methods getAllLegs and getLegMap?

Comment: @MauricePerry:  getAllLegs will return the outer hashmap which will correspond to the number of columns of table. getLegMap will return the inner hashmap which will correspond to the rows of the table. Thanks for your time.. Appreciate your looking into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    #set ($allLegs = $ConfirmationObject.getAllLegs())
    #set ($columns = $allLegs.keySet())
    #set ($maxCols = 3)
    #set ($groups = ($columns.size() + $maxCols - 1)/$maxCols)
    #set ($lastGroup = $groups - 1)

    #foreach ($group in [0..$lastGroup])
    #if($group >0 )
    <br>
    <br>
    #end
    <table style="font-family:Arial;font-size:xx-small;color:black" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     #set ($allLegs = $ConfirmationObject.getAllLegs())
     #set ($i = (($group*$maxCols)+1))
     #set ($groupLegs = $ConfirmationObject.getGrouplLegSet($group, $maxCols))

     <tr>
      <td valign="top" width="30%"> </td>
       #foreach($legSzie in $groupLegs.keySet())
        <td valign="top" width="30%" align="left"><b>Leg $i</b></td>
         #set ($i=$i+1)
       #end
      <td></td>
      <td valign="top" width="10%" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>

     <td colspan="1">
      <table style="font-family:Arial;font-size:xx-small;color:black" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
       #set ($map = $ConfirmationObject.getLegMap(1))
       #foreach($key in $map.keySet())
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" width="60%">$key </td>
        </tr>
       #end
      </table>
     </td>

     #foreach($legString in $groupLegs.keySet())
     <td colspan="1">
      <table style="font-family:Arial;font-size:xx-small;color:black" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
       #set ($legMap = $allLegs.get($legString))
       #foreach($legKey in $legMap.keySet())
        <tr>
         <td >$legMap.get($legKey)</td>
        </tr>
       #end
      </table>
     </td>
   #end
  </table>
 #end
```

Here we wrote a java method **getGrouplLegSet($group, $maxCols)**. The method would just return sub-set of hashmap based on the group and maxCols. So for example if the group is 0 then values from 0 till 2 will be returned, if group value is 1 then sub map from 3 till 5 will be returned and so on..

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like that:

```
#set ($columns = $allLegs.keySet().toArray())
#set ($maxCols = 3)
#set ($groups = ($columns.size() + $maxCols - 1)/$maxCols)
#set ($lastGroup = $groups - 1)
#foreach ($group in [0..$lastGroup])
    <table style="font-family:Arial;font-size:xx-small;color:black" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    #set ($firstCol = $maxCols*$group )
    #set ($lastCol = $firstCol + $maxCols - 1)
    #if ($lastCol >= $columns.size())
       #set ($lastCol = $columns.size() - 1)
    #end
        <tr>
            <th></th>
    #foreach ($col in [$firstCol..$lastCol])
            <th>$columns[$col]</th>
    #end
        </tr>

    #set ($rows = $allLegs.get($columns[$firstCol]).keySet())
    #foreach($row in $rows)
        <tr>
            <th>$row</th>
    #foreach ($col in [$firstCol..$lastCol])
        #set ($legMap = $allLegs.get($columns[$col]))
            <td>$legMap.get($row)</td>
    #end
        </tr>
     #end
</table>

#end
```

Comment: Thanks a zillion for your help/guidance. Your answer did not solve my problem exactly but it gave me enough hints to finally reach a solution. So i will still accept your answer. Pasted below is my solution by modifying your piece of code. Thanks again buddy